# Where's the settings of GitHub repository? I just want to delete him

Tags: github, repository, settings

How to delete my repository on GitHub?

[image]

Comment: I can't to find Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you signed in? If not, you need to sign into your account. Once you have done that, the settings button should be there. If not, just add '/settings' to the URL of your repository, and load that page. Once you are in settings, scroll to the bottom where it says 'danger zone' and click 'delete this repository'.

Answer (score 0):

When you're logged in, there's a settings tab when you are viewing your repository. From there you can delete it.

[image]